# custom filter query for flask using sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, filter, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make filter in postgre sql table that have varchar and integer column. And I need to apply filter.
For example I have a category table as below:

```
id    name    rank
1     test1   1
2     test2   2
3     test3   3
```

And I want to apply filter in slqalchemy in flask as below:

```
filter_text = "%{}%".format(request.args.get('search[value]'))
filter_int = request.args.get(['search[value]')
if(filter_text):
    categories = Category.query.filter(
        (Category.category_name.like(filter_text)) | 
        (Category.rank == filter_int)
    ).all()
else:
    categories = Category.query.all()
```

I get search[value] from the input field which can be both integer and alphabet or both.
When I run code and pass alphabet I get error while I pass search['value'] = 't':

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: "t"
```

I know the issue is due to alphabet passed in rank column which is integer. But I want to search in all column using same single input field.

Answer (score 1):

you need to typecast the query column based on your condition. Thanks